# Memory leak with std::string

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks

The following code :

```
#include <string>

void *ptr = nullptr;
std::string *p = new std::string();
*p = "1";
ptr = p;
delete ptr;
```

seems to make a memory leak with the following output :

> 21: Detected memory leaks!
>
> 21: Dumping objects ->
>
> 21: {706} normal block at 0x00723860, 8 bytes long.
>
> 21:  Data: <  q     > C8 04 71 00 00 00 00 00
>
> 21: Object dump complete.

It is weird since the following code shows no mistake (works also for *double*, *bool*) :

```
void *ptr = nullptr;
int *p = new int();
*p = 1;
ptr = p;
delete ptr;
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?
(I need to use a "void *" pointer since it may keep different types of objects).
Many thanks to the ones who can help me !!! :)

Comment: C++ has better ways of dealing with different types than `void*`. For example [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: @risingDarkness I am starting with C++. If you could give some clue for other types than "void *" to use, it will be great !

Comment: This makes no sense at all: `ptr = *p;`. That shouldn't even *compile*. And regarding what "worked", `int` has the most trivial of trivial destructors (*none*). The same cannot be said for `std::string`.

Comment: Don't use void pointers. C++ is built for safe typing, void* eliminates that.

Comment: Depending on the problem you need to solve, you have some options like boost::any that I mentioned before, inheritance or even templates. Without more information on your specific case I can't really recommend the best option.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are absolutely right. That was my mistake and I've corrected it : it is indeed `ptr = p` that should have written in the first place

Comment: is this "thing" being returned an abstract "handle" you're desiring to hide in a `void*` ? It matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Assuming that you meant `ptr = p`).

If you pass a `void *` to `delete`, no destructor is called.
(There is no way for the compiler to even know if there is one, so there is no way to call it.)

Since `std::string` internally holds a dynamically allocated buffer, that buffer is leaked if the destructor isn't called.

You'll need to maintain "proper" pointers, either through templates, `boost::any`, a common base class with a virtual destructor, or manual bookkeeping.

Comment: It’s weird that this answer fail to mention templates. Surely templates are the *obvious*, *idiomatic* solution here unless we know that they cannot be used (runtime polymorphism required). It’s almost certain that this would solve OP’s problem better than all other mechanisms proposed.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I actually did mention templates.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's not weird, it's senility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which made me understand the problem !

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

> The operand shall be of pointer to object type or of class type. If of
>   class type, the operand is contextually implicitly converted (Clause
>   4) to a pointer to object type.

And further in a footnote there is written that

> 81) This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of
>   type void* because void is not an object type.

So the behaviour of the program is undefined. Neither the destructor for the object of type `std::string` is called nor the operator function delete because the size of the object is unknown.